# Error initializing capture component: 0, 480, 360

Tags: iphone, ios5, augmented-reality

I get "Error initializing capture component: 0, 480, 360" when I try to run metaio SDK sample project on ios 6 simulator iphone. I was able to compile but I got the same error before and after the compile.How to solve this issue?

**Metaio sdk**

```
Error initializing capture component: 0, 480, 360
Error starting capture component
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might get the error message above when you try to run your application on iOS simulator.Please run on your **ios device(iphone or ipad)**.You cannot take image via Mac's webcam from iPhone Simulator. For camera, you need to test it on a device.

```
if( m_metaioSDK )
{
    m_metaioSDK->startCamera(0, 480, 360);
}
```